# How do I switch back to lightdm after upgrading to Gnome 3.4?

Tags: lightdm, login-screen

my lightdm became curious look like in the picture. how to restore the original look like Ubuntu?[image: lightdm]

Comment: It would help if you would edit your question explaining the modifications you made to the default login screen

Comment: It appears you have somehow switched to GDM instead of LightDM. Please open a terminal and run sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm; you will get a selection box, select LightDM and then OK. Reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install unity-greeter and configure lightdm to use it.  You are running the gtk greeter now for some reason.  When lightdm is mis-configured it enters "low graphics" mode.  You can confirm the reason by looking at /var/log/lightdm.log

Make sure unity-greeter is installed.  You can easily do this by just reinstalling it with apt **sudo apt-get install unity-greeter**.

Edit lightdm.conf, it should look like this (below), the key line being "greeter-session=unity-greeter"

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
```

After you do that, start lightdm from a virtual terminal.  **sudo initctl start lightdm**.  I'm not sure if lightdm is "running" when in low-graphics mode, if so, stop it first with **sudo initctl stop lightdm**.

Note: You do NOT need to uninstall the lightdm-gtk-greeter, just leave it for a backup or once everything is working, then you can remove it if you want.