# How do you remove a stubborn Lubuntu-desktop environment after changing ubuntu's default login screen?

Tags: lubuntu, 10.04, wubi, login-screen, desktop-environments

I installed Ubuntu 10.4 Lucid (using WUBI) on an old Dell I use mostly for emails. 
I then installed Lubuntu-desktop environment but now I want to remove it.

When I run the command `sudo apt-get remove lubuntu desktop` it says such environment is not installed.

Reason I want to remove it: It changed my default Ubuntu login screen to Lubuntu's login AND it does not recognize my user or password. (I can only log in rebooting then safe graphic mode).

I've tried editing the lightdm..conf file, as I found solutions online about it, but it is also not installed. 
I've tried removing lubuntu dependent files in synaptic but it they just bring  a script error when trying to do so.

Command `$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/` lists

```
lubuntu.notebook.desktop` 

 lubuntu.desktop`
```

Comment: 10.04 is [EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) which means it isn't supported here.

Comment: Even though this question WAS CLOSED by some guy who thinks the question is irrelevant. I DO THINK THAT UBUNTU IS THE SAME REGARDLESS OF WHAT VERSION USE. THE PRINCIPLES OF FIXING IT ARE THE SAME. Please see my solutions to my problems in my following comments

Comment: I managed to find the solutions for my problems in the following links:           http://askubuntu.com/questions/371742/how-to-restore-ubuntu-login-screen-after-lubuntu-install

Comment: Also this helped:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234955

Comment: THIS link also helped:   http://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter

Comment: This one reset the greeter beautifully:   http://askubuntu.com/questions/166232/how-do-i-switch-back-to-lightdm-after-upgrading-to-gnome-3-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy paste this excellent guide:
[Getting Back to a Pure Gnome on Ubuntu 10.04](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnomelucid)

Comment: Thank you but I did that 'before' posting my question and it does now work.  They system keeps bringing back that log in option. Arrrg!